# Unresolved external symbol for classmethod that isn't even referenced

Tags: c++, c++11, linker-errors, unresolved-external

I'm creating a simple debug thread name database (because you can't give thread a name in windows, you can only send that name to debugger). I have this header file:

### `threadname.h`

```
class ThreadNameMap {
public:
    void setThreadName( uint32_t id, const std::string &name );

    std::string getThreadName( const uint32_t id ) const;
    // If ID given as string
    std::string getThreadName( const std::string id ) const;
    // If no ID given, current ID is used
    std::string getThreadName( ) const;

    // A singleton getter
    static ThreadNameMap* ThreadNameMap::getInstance();
    // Static getters that use the singleton
    static std::string getName( const uint32_t id );
    static std::string getName( const std::string id );
    static std::string getName( );
private:
    ThreadNameMap() {maxNameLength = 16;};
    int maxNameLength;
    // Map of ids and names
    std::map<uint32_t, std::string> names;
};
```

This is the implementation:

#### `threadname.cpp`

```
ThreadNameMap* ThreadNameMap::getInstance() {
    static ThreadNameMap inst = ThreadNameMap();
    return &inst;
}

std::string ThreadNameMap::getName( const uint32_t id ) { return getInstance()->getThreadName(id); }
std::string ThreadNameMap::getName( const std::string id ) { return getInstance()->getThreadName(id); }
std::string ThreadNameMap::getName( ) { return getInstance()->getThreadName(); }

void ThreadNameMap::setThreadName( uint32_t id, const std::string &name ) {
    setThreadName_private(id, name.c_str());
    if(id==-1)
        id = boostThreadId();
    names[id] = name;
}

std::string ThreadNameMap::getThreadName( const uint32_t id ) const {
    if( names.count( id )>0)
        return names.at(id);
    else
        return "";
}
std::string ThreadNameMap::getThreadName( const std::string id ) const {
    uint32_t threadNumber = 0;
    sscanf(id.c_str(), "%lx", &threadNumber);
    return getThreadName(threadNumber);
}
/** THIS ONE IS REPORTED AS UNREFERENCED!!! **/
std::string ThreadNameMap::getThreadName( ) const {
    return getThreadName(boostThreadId());
}
```

I use singleton interface and I access it like this in my logger header file:

## `logger.h`

```
#include "... path .../setthreadname.h"
#define LOGMTDBG_tmp(debuglevel, logstream) LOGMT(debugLevel(debuglevel) << datetimeEx << ' ' << ThreadNameMap::getName() << ' ' << __FUNCTION__ << ' ' << logstream)
```

Logger is included in many and many other `cpp` and `h` files - wherever needed. And some of those report unreferenced symbol:

```
Error   13  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > __cdecl ThreadNameMap::getThreadName(void)" (?getThreadName@ThreadNameMap@@QEAA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)   D:\techsys\RomeoTT\Source\RunWindow.obj
Error   14  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > __cdecl ThreadNameMap::getThreadName(void)" (?getThreadName@ThreadNameMap@@QEAA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __cdecl BaseRunPresenter::MessageHandler(class boost::shared_ptr)" (?MessageHandler@BaseRunPresenter@@AEAAXV?$shared_ptr@USMSSBase@@@boost@@@Z)    D:\techsys\RomeoTT\Source\BaseRunPresenter.obj
Error   15  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > __cdecl ThreadNameMap::getThreadName(void)" (?getThreadName@ThreadNameMap@@QEAA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)   D:\techsys\RomeoTT\Source\BaseRunView.obj
Error   16  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > __cdecl ThreadNameMap::getThreadName(void)" (?getThreadName@ThreadNameMap@@QEAA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)   D:\techsys\RomeoTT\Source\XmlSestavaRunPresenter.obj
Error   17  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > __cdecl ThreadNameMap::getThreadName(void)" (?getThreadName@ThreadNameMap@@QEAA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)   D:\techsys\RomeoTT\Source\RunSestavaFrame.obj
Error   18  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > __cdecl getThreadName(void)" (?getThreadName@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl SestavaHeader::DataSource::Dump2LOG(void)const " (?Dump2LOG@DataSource@SestavaHeader@@QEBAXXZ)  D:\techsys\RomeoTT\Source\SestavaDataSource.obj
```

I **searched the project**, but there is not a single reference of any of the class non static methods, only the one in **`logger.h`**.

I checked many of the Unreferenced external symbol questions, but they all came with two possibilities:

1. dll is missing - well, I'm not using any dll for this obviously
2. Function was declared but not implemented - in the code above you can see both declaration and implementation and **they are matching**

So why would linker complain about method that is not even referenced? I tried to alter `const` and move static method in `.h` file, nothing helped. I'm really desperate now.

**Edit:** Visual studio linker flags:

```
/OUT:"D:\techsys\RomeoTT\PROJECT\PROJECTd.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"..\..\libs\openssl64\lib\VC\static" /LIBPATH:"..\..\libs\boost155\stage\lib64bit" /LIBPATH:"C:\Qt\5.3.0-64\qtbase\lib" "libeay32MTd.lib" "Graph64d.lib" "HelpLib64d.lib" "version.lib" "qtmaind.lib" "Qt5Cored.lib" "Qt5Guid.lib" "Qt5Multimediad.lib" "Qt5Sqld.lib" "Qt5PrintSupportd.lib" "Qt5Svgd.lib" "Qt5Widgetsd.lib" "Qt5Xmld.lib" "Qt5XmlPatternsd.lib" "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /MANIFEST /ManifestFile:"D:\techsys\XXXX\obj\x64\XXXX\Debug\XXXXXd.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ALLOWISOLATION /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"D:\techsys\XXXXX\XXXXX64\XXXXXd.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /OPT:NOREF /PGD:"D:\techsys\XXXX\XXXX64\XXXXXd.pgd" /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X64 /ERRORREPORT:NONE
```

Comment: And you do build with `threadname.cpp` and link with the object file generated by the source file?

Comment: What are the compiler and linker flags you are using?

Comment: Well actually, everything worked before I exposed the class in header file. I started by exposing a function and in `cpp`, calling class from that function. I'll add compiler and linker flags but I doubt that's relevant, I just use devault visual studio flags.

Comment: have a look at the source code the linker is complaining about. This appears to be calling getThreadName() directly (your logger is calling getName).
Also one of your files is callin getThreadName without a class name (last line of the error)

Comment: @TomTanner I searched the project for `getThreadName` case insensitive string and only found refferences in `threadname.cpp`. This is why I said that the function is not refferenced.

Comment: Invocation is here: `std::string ThreadNameMap::getName( ) { return getInstance()->getThreadName(); }`

Comment: @DanielStrul but that invocation happens in `cpp` file, so can't possibly be a linker error.

Comment: Because the method is declared in the header file, the compiler has no reason to complain. However, the linker tries to effectively find the method, and doesn't find it anywhere, hence the linker error

Comment: @DanielStrul Is there anything I can do to find out why it can't find the method? I want to remind that when I used functions instead of class, it worked. I am strongly considering going back to procedural approach, but I am also curious why this happens. Maybe the `threadname.obj` is not created? How do I change that?

Comment: It looks like the files `RunWindow.obj` et al is referring to the symbol. How about sharing the offending source? By the way how about a minimal, complete, verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Preparing a MCVE itself could in fact reveal the problem.

Comment: I still think it is related to the implementation being a const member function, while the header advertises a non-const member function. There is no implementation for a non-const `getName()`.

Comment: @skyking the project is about 50MB corporate source. And please trust me, all refferences to my functions come from that one call in the `logger.h` file, I didn't edit the other files, nor did anyone else for quite a while.

Comment: @PeterSchneider But `getName(void)` is non const in both cases (`static` cannot be const) and `getThreadName(void)` is `const` in both cases.

Comment: I concur with Peter: if it worked with functions but fails with methods, it looks like a constness issue. Can you do a full rebuild of the project, just in case an obsolete reference to a previous non-const declaration is laying somewhere in the build cache?

Comment: @Tomas you are right, that cannot be it unless I miss something else...

Comment: @DanielStrul I started clean build, but it will take 30 minutes. I told you the project is huge... :) It's indeed possible that changing a macro confused the compiler.

Comment: @TomášZato That's even more reason to create a **minimal**, complete, verifiable example. If you're so sure that the reference come from the posted source then you should be able to pinpoint your problem, but you obviously haven't since you ask. If it were that all references were in the posted code you should be able to just wrap it up and make it complete (and see if the problem is verifiable in that example).

Comment: @skyking having an answer now, tell me do you think I'd ever manage to produce accidentally broken `obj` files?

Comment: @TomášZato Yes, that's a posibillity. How do you think we should be able to conclude that from the code you posted? If you instead had created a MCVE it would have been obvious to you that the problem would have been solved by a clean build already, and you wouldn't have to ask the question.

Comment: @skyking Yeah sure, if everyone had the time, skills and patience to fix their problems all by themselves, we could have another porn site instead of StackOverflow. MCVE yourself, if you enjoy being helplessly stuck on a problem you don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You find the likely culprit by examining in detail the error messages (cleaned-up for lisibility):

```
Unresolved external symbol "string stringThreadNameMap::getThreadName(void)" referenced in RunWindow.obj
Unresolved external symbol "string stringThreadNameMap::getThreadName(void)" referenced in function "private: void stringBaseRunPresenter::MessageHandler(class boost::shared_ptr)" referenced in BaseRunPresenter.obj
Unresolved external symbol "string stringThreadNameMap::getThreadName(void)" referenced in BaseRunView.obj
Unresolved external symbol "string stringThreadNameMap::getThreadName(void)" referenced in XmlSestavaRunPresenter.obj
Unresolved external symbol "string stringThreadNameMap::getThreadName(void)" referenced in RunSestavaFrame.obj
Unresolved external symbol "string stringThreadNameMap::getThreadName(void)" referenced in function "public: void stringSestavaHeader::DataSource::Dump2LOG(void)const " SestavaDataSource.obj
```

What these linker errors say is that:

- Some object files (RunWindow.obj, BaseRunPresenter.obj...) contain a reference to a **non-const** method `getThreadName()`
- It implies that these object files have been generated from source files at a time when the method `getThreadName()` was declared **non-const**

However, the declaration of `getThreadName()` is now **const**:

```
std::string getThreadName( ) const;
```

Thus, each of these object files have been compiled based on an obsolete declaration of `getThreadName()` and should be recompiled. If possible, as there may be other (undetected) inconsistency errors, you should perform a full rebuild.